# transformRequest: angular.identity not working in angular-4

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload, http-headers, multipartform-data

I am trying to send files using Form-data, but this script is not working in angular-4, although it works in angular-2

```
var fd = new FormData();
var datas = $("#fileForm").serializeArray();
// send other data in the form
for( var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++ ) {
    fd.append(datas[i].name, datas[i].value);
};
// append file to FormData
fd.append("file", $("#fileInput")[0].files[0])
// for sending manual values
fd.append("email", this.email+'');
fd.append("category", this.cate+'');
fd.append("pricepackage", this.pkg+'');
fd.append("duration", this.pkg_d+'');
fd.append("secret_key", this.srt_key+'');

var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/func/textfile_sent/";
this.http_obj.post(url,fd, {
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
    transformRequest : angular.identity
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  // this callback will be called asynchronously
  // when the response is available
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  // called asynchronously if an error occurs
  // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

It is showing an error at `transformRequest : angular.identity` and the error is:

> TS2345:Argument of type '{ headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined; }; transformRequest: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'transformRequest' does not exist in type 'RequestOptionsArgs'

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear in which version of Angular this has change, if ever, but in the current version of Angular, `RequestOptionsArgs` has only the following properties:

body, headers, method, params, responseType, search, url, withCredentials.

So just change your code to this:

```
//...
this.http_obj.post(url,fd, {
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}, //remove the extraneous property
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config)
```